Python retrieve Google Keep data of personal account
I'd like to build an app that interacts with my Google keep data (edit, add, delete).
I have created a new Google Cloud project and enabled the Google Keep API as well as created a new service account for accessing the API.
I've created credentials for the service account and downloaded them. I have created the below code to call the API with the service account but obviously it will not return anything as it is accessing it's own data.
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/keep']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'credentials.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,
    scopes=SCOPES
)

service = build("keep", "v1", credentials=credentials)
l = service.notes().list().execute()
print(l)

I have tried adding the service account email address as a collaborator on one of my notes in Google keep but the above code still returns only an empty dict, and after refreshing Keep the added service account also vanishes as a collaborator, so I suspect it's not possible to add them there.
Does anyone know if this is possible at all or how to Google Keep operations on personal accounts via APIs?
Edit:
I have tried using OAuth credentials as well, but there doesn't seem to be any Keep API scopes available for it.

Try OAuth2 instead of a service account. Create OAuth2 credentials in Google Cloud and download client_secret.json. Use the OAuth2 flow to get user consent and generate an access token. Install dependencies: "pip install google-auth google-auth-oauthlib google-auth-httplib2 google-api-python-client". Implement the code to authenticate and call the Google Keep API. Save tokens in token.json for future use.

I have tried that, but it seems that there is no appropriate scope available for the keep api
